# How to reindex the magento2 site from a remote system

Tags: magento2, reindex

How to reindex the magento2 site from a remote system.Please help me to find this.Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you tell what is the OS running in your remote system.

Answer (score -1):

Magento offers a command line tool, which also allows reindexing. By running the following:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Comment: If the root folder is in the local host means i can run this commend.but this case the root folder is not in the local host that is located in a remote system. i should reindex from my local host